# Expo - When navigating to IOS settings via linking, an error is thrown

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to send the user to my app IOS settings using expo linking:

The component:

```
<Card disabled={true}>
              <Text>{isSettingModalOpen}</Text>
              <Button onPress={() => setIsSettingModalOpen(null)}>
                DISMISS
              </Button>
              <Button
                onPress={() => {
                  openAppSettings();
                }}
              >
                Go To Settings
              </Button>
</Card>
```

The logic of the open settings button:

```
export const openAppSettings = async () => {
  try {
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      await Linking.openURL("app-settings:");
    } else {
      const pkg = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel
        ? Constants.manifest.android.package build
        : "host.exp.exponent"; 

      await IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
        IntentLauncher.ActivityAction.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
        { data: "package:" + pkg }
      );
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error -openAppSettings-", e);
  }
};
```

On android devices this code works without any issues, but on IOS devices,
when we press on "go to settings button" we get the error:

`Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`

We aren't using any refs at our project so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import * as IntentLauncher from 'expo-intent-launcher'

const openAppPref = () => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            Linking.openURL("App-prefs:root=General");
        } else {
            IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
                IntentLauncher.ActivityAction.SECURITY_SETTINGS
            )
        }
    }
```

you can simply open like this
in ios you can easily use Linking but in android you should use Intent launcher from expo